# how to change a column to a row based on relationships?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so I'm relatively new to SQL, work in education, and nearly everything I've learned about SQL I've learned from this site.  So thank you!  Now, I've searched for an answer to my question and haven't had luck so far.  I've looked into PIVOT, UNPIVOT, UNION ALL, and CROSS APPLY, and so far I do not think those solutions will give me what I need.  At least I've been unsuccessful trying to get it to work.

I have two tables I'm dealing with.  One is called STU and one is called TCH.  As you can imagine 1 is for students and the other teachers.  There are a few fields that we need to know what they are.  STU.ID is the student ID.  Lets say we have 1-999 of these.  STU.SC which is the school code (1-5) the student is assigned to, and STU.CU which states which teacher the student has.  TCH has TCH.TN which is the teacher number and matches STU.CU. (1-40) and TCH.SC which will match STU.SC

currently my query looks as such: (I do know given the information I provided I would only need to query the STU table in my example, I have other things I'll be querying and wanted to make sure the join was present.  I cut the amount of fields down for the example for simplicity's sake.)

```
select TCH.TN
STU.SC,
STU.ID 
From TCH Left Join STU on
STU.SC=TCH.SC and STU.CU=TCH.TN 
where STU.SC  > 2
and STU.SC <= 5
```

a truncated result of this would look similar to this example and give results for all 1000 students.

```
TCH.TN    STU.SC    STU.ID
---------------------------
24         3         243
32         5         145
24         3         567
21         4         098
21         4         923
24         3         417
```

The request I have is to have the data output like so:

```
TCH.TN    STU.SC    STU.ID    STU.ID    STU.ID    STU.ID    STU.ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------
24         3         243       567       417
32         5         145
21         4         098       923
```

Some of these classes would have upwards of 30 students the IDs pretty much at random.  How would you guys make this work?  Please also remember I'm still new to SQL and an ELI5 would be fantastic if possible.

Thank you

Comment: So how many columns would you like to have in the output? Fixed size of N + 2 or the maximum of STU.SC + 2?

Comment: Your tables are not "normalized". A teacher's reference in student table is enough to join the tables. School ID is redundant in student table (can be fetched from teacher table by join) unless there is heavy querying on that field and you wish to retain that data for performance reasons.

Comment: Now on the query itself: This is ideally a job of a programming language to roll up  information into multiple columns. If your query is piped to some report and you do not have a programming language (PL/SQL or Java or Python) involved, it is okay to try with Pivot and give this a shot. Else It's way more maintainable and understandable with some code.

Comment: Are you on SQL Server? (as opposed to mySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) And if so, what version are you on?

Comment: You should specify the RDBMS in your question and tag it properly. Only if you have a fixed max number of columns it is doable with a (long) cASE statement. Otherwhise you need a procedure or to do it in the application

Comment: @greenshade essentially all of the students tied to a teacher.

Comment: @swapz83 yes you are right, what was not explained in my post was that teacher numbers are unique across schools but not across the district which is why I had to add the SC field as well.  Sorry about missing that point.  I don't have any coding knowledge unfortunately, I did try pivot but I it seemed to me like pivot wanted me to populate the IDs as fields?  Like, I couldn't just designate STU.ID for as many students as would be there, I would have to manually set the ID as the column header.  Unless I was understanding it wrong, which is very possible.

Comment: @tarheel SQL Server 2012, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic pivot to resolve this problem.

Below is sample code although, I didn't run it.

```
    select TCH.TN as TeacherId
STU.SC as studentScollar,
STU.ID as studentId 
INTO #tmp
From TCH Left Join STU on
STU.SC=TCH.SC and STU.CU=TCH.TN 
where STU.SC  > 2
and STU.SC <= 5


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(studentId)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT studentId FROM #tmp) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT TeacherId, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #tmp
    PIVOT(SUM(studentScollar) 
          FOR studentId IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

For your reference below is dynamic pivot link
http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: I tried that out, but unfortunately I have too much data.  I kept it simple above but I have almost 10000 students and approximately 400ish teachers.  When I try the query I get "The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements." :(

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Pivot Statements, all of the headers from the final query must be unique. See the excerpt from the [Microsoft Documentation on Pivots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

> You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table. PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the **unique values** from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output, and performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining column values that are wanted in the final output.

Because you want to have the first 2 columns `[tch.tn], [stu.sc]` stay as rows and the 3rd column `[stu.id]` to both be aggregated and be the value that becomes the header in the pivot statement it is creating one column per student. (Thats why you get the error mentioned in response to Rajat's answer.)

What you need to do instead is create a new column to pivot the values into headers, and aggregate (only use `max()`) the values of the `stu.id` column. In other words, make the same number of columns as there are students in the largest class (if the largest class size is 30, then it will generate 30 columns).

**Answer:**

```
use db_nm

--declaring variables to build my dynamic SQL statement later
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    , @col_list nvarchar(max)

--building the sample data
if object_id('tempdb..##tmp_stu_id_tbl') is not null
    drop table ##tmp_stu_id_tbl

if object_id('tempdb..##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot') is not null
    drop table ##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot

create table ##tmp_stu_id_tbl ([tn] int not null, [sc] int not null, [id] int not null)

insert into ##tmp_stu_id_tbl
values (24, 3, 243)
    , (32, 5, 145)
    , (24, 3, 567)
    , (21, 4, 098)
    , (21, 4, 923)
    , (24, 3, 417)

--Using this query to add a column with values 
--that will become the column headers after the pivot
select a.[tn]
, a.[sc]
--this creates the value id.1 for the first row id it finds
--within each tn/sc combination
, 'stu_id_' + cast(row_number() over (partition by a.[tn], a.[sc] order by a.[id]) as varchar(10)) as piv_col
, a.[id]
into ##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot
from ##tmp_stu_id_tbl as a

--creating the column list for the dynamic sql statement
set @col_list = (select stuff((select distinct ', [' + a.piv_col + ']'
                from ##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot as a
                for xml path('')),1,1,''))

--building the dynamic SQL
set @sql = '
select tn
, sc
, ' + @col_list +
' from ##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot 
pivot (max([id]) for piv_col in (' + @col_list + ')) as p'

--executing the dynamic SQL
exec (@sql);
```

**Result:**

```
tch_tn stu_sc stu.id.1 stu.id.2 stu.id.3
  24      3     243      417      567
  21      4     98       923      NULL
  32      5     145      NULL     NULL
```

**Edit:**

```
select TCH.TN,
STU.SC,
STU.ID,
'stu_id_' + cast(row_number() over (partition by tch.[tn], stu.[sc] order by stu.[id]) as varchar(10)) as piv_col
into ##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot
From TCH Left Join STU on
STU.SC=TCH.SC and STU.CU=TCH.TN 
where STU.SC  > 2
and STU.SC <= 5
```

Comment: Ok, so where your inserting in the values, insert into '##tmp_stu_id_tbl
values (24, 3, 243)
    , (32, 5, 145)
    , (24, 3, 567)
    , (21, 4, 098)
    , (21, 4, 923)
    , (24, 3, 417)' do I need to manually enter the data, or is there a way to pull it using the fields?  a lot of this is new for me so forgive me if it's a stupid question.

Comment: @RyanMcKay No problem at all, that insert statement was to help me build my answer with your sample data. I made 2 edits to the answer above. First, was to remove the aliases (`stu, tch`), as my original answer was built thinking that was part of the column name because they were included in the column names of the example data output. Second, was adding the Edit section where it shows a way for you to achieve the same goal via querying your tables, into the `##tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot` table.

Comment: Excellent thank you.  I will try this and grt back to you

Comment: Ok, I was able to try this this morning and I'm getting an error. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "a.tn" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "a.sc" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "a.id" could not be bound.  I looked into that error and from what I'm reading its saying I'm not joining my tables correctly?  I'm not quite sure, the join works without the aliases you added, I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this though.  Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @RyanMcKay Apologies, i forgot to change the aliases on my line that I added to your original query. You should see the edit above where what used to be `a.tn` is now `tch.tn` along with the other columns changing accordingly.

Comment: Oh gotcha!  I had tried adding it as 'partition by [tch.tn]' and so on but that didn't work. Now I see how I should have set it. So I ran the query, but I didn't get results.  Instead I just got the answer '6351 rows effected', which I'm assuming is the data being put into the tmp_stu_id_pre_pivot table, but I can't find that tmp table to pull from with another query?

Comment: That means that the records are successfully going into the temp table, and that is the number of records going into it. That query is simply to replace my insert statements, but you still need to run variables created and the drop table calls at the beginning of my answer, as well as everything below this line: `--creating the column list for the dynamic sql statement`.